# What is the "const" keyword used for in Dart?

Tags: dart

Can someone explain to me how/when/why to use `const` keyword, or it is just "a way to declare a constant variable"? If so, what's the difference between this :

```
int x = 5;
```

and

```
const int x = 5;
```

Could you guys please give me an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the difference in between ''const'' and ''final'' keyword in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50431055/608639)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`const` means compile time constant. The expression value must be known at compile time. `const` modifies "values".

From [news.dartlang.org](http://news.dartlang.org/2012/06/const-static-final-oh-my.html),

> "const" has a meaning that's a bit more complex and subtle in Dart.
> const modifies *values*. You can use it when creating collections,
> like const [1, 2, 3], and when constructing objects (instead of new)
> like const Point(2, 3). Here, const means that the object's entire
> deep state can be determined entirely at compile time and that the
> object will be frozen and completely immutable.

if you use

`const x = 5` then variable x can be used in a const collection like

```
const aConstCollection = const [x];
```

if you don't use `const`, and just use `x = 5` then

`const aConstCollection = const [x];` is illegal.

More examples from [www.dartlang.org](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/m1-language-changes/#support-const-modifier-for-variables)

```
class SomeClass {
  static final someConstant = 123;
  static final aConstList = const [someConstant]; //NOT allowed
}

class SomeClass {
  static const someConstant = 123; // OK
  static final startTime = new DateTime.now(); // OK too
  static const aConstList = const [someConstant]; // also OK
}
```

Comment: why can't I use const without static? My const doesn't need static class scope so why am I forced to use declare it as static?

Comment: @robbie your constant also doesn't need to be repeated for each instance.  Since it is constant, it will never change, so why waste space duplicating it?  By forcing static declaration of constants, they are only put into memory once for the class, rather than each time an instance is created.  I believe that this explanation applies to both C# and Dart.

Comment: Const values in Dart are "canonicalized", so there is only ever one instance of them, and "static const" is therefore redundant: "const" would be sufficient. The last paragraph of [Seth Ladd's article on this](http://news.dartlang.org/2012/06/const-static-final-oh-my.html) in fact suggests that "const" is the preferred style and "static const" discouraged.

Comment: What's the difference between `final` and `const` then?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431055/what-is-the-difference-in-between-const-and-final-keyword-in-dart/51448666#51448666

Answer (score 3):

Here are some facts about `const` values:

- The value must be known at compile time.

  ```dart
  const x = 5; // OK
  ```
- Anything that is calculated at runtime can't be `const`.

  ```dart
  const x = 5.toDouble(); // Not OK
  ```
- A `const` value means that it's deeply constant, that is, every one of its members is constant recursively.

  ```dart
  const x = [5.0, 5.0];          // OK
  const x = [5.0, 5.toDouble()]; // Not OK
  ```
- You can create `const` constructors. That means that it is possible to create `const` values from the class.

  ```dart
  class MyConstClass {
    final int x;
    const MyConstClass(this.x);
  }

  const myValue = MyConstClass(5); // OK
  ```
- `const` values are canonical instances. That means that there is only a single instance no matter how many you declare.

  ```dart
  main() {
    const a = MyConstClass(5);
    const b = MyConstClass(5);
    print(a == b); // true
  }

  class MyConstClass {
    final int x;
    const MyConstClass(this.x);
  }
  ```
- If you have a class member that is `const`, you must also mark it as `static`. `static` means it belongs to the class. Since there is only ever one instance of `const` values, it wouldn't make sense for it to not be `static`.

  ```dart
  class MyConstClass {
    static const x = 5;
  }
  ```

#### See also

- [Dart Const Tutorial – All You Need to Know (Const Expressions, Canonical Instances and More)](https://resocoder.com/2020/01/06/dart-const-tutorial-all-you-need-to-know-const-expressions-canonical-instances-and-more/)