# What is the difference between the "const" and "final" keywords in Dart?

Tags: dart, constants, keyword, final

What is the difference between the `const` and `final` keywords in Dart?

Comment: Here is some detail about `const`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51576209/flutter-variable-with-const-keyword/51576842#51576842 and the simple explonation to `final` is constant(cannot reassign or assign once created with final keyword) and you have to initialize it once.

Answer (score 693, accepted):

[There is a post on dart's website and it explains it pretty well.](https://news.dartlang.org/2012/06/const-static-final-oh-my.html)

**Final:**

> "final" means single-assignment: a final variable or field *must* have an initializer. Once assigned a value, a final variable's value cannot be changed. final modifies *variables*.

---

**Const:**

> "const" has a meaning that's a bit more complex and subtle in Dart. const modifies *values*. You can use it when creating collections, like const [1, 2, 3], and when constructing objects (instead of new) like const Point(2, 3). Here, const means that the object's entire deep state can be determined entirely at compile time and that the object will be frozen and completely immutable.

> Const objects have a couple of interesting properties and restrictions:

> They must be created from data that can be calculated at compile time. A const object does not have access to anything you would need to calculate at runtime. 1 + 2 is a valid const expression, but new DateTime.now() is not.

> They are deeply, transitively immutable. If you have a final field containing a collection, that collection can still be mutable. If you have a const collection, everything in it must also be const, recursively.

> They are *canonicalized*. This is sort of like string interning: for any given const value, a single const object will be created and re-used no matter how many times the const expression(s) are evaluated.

---

### So, what does this mean?

**Const:**
If the value you have is computed at runtime (`new DateTime.now()`, for example), you can **not** use a const for it. However, if the value is known at compile time (`const a = 1;`), then you should use `const` over `final`. There are 2 other large differences between `const` and `final`. Firstly, if you're using `const` inside a class, you have to declare it as `static const` rather than just `const`. Secondly, if you have a `const` collection, everything inside of that is in `const`. If you have a `final` collection, everything inside of that is **not** `final`.

**Final:**
`final` should be used over `const` if you don't know the value at compile time, and it will be calculated/grabbed at runtime. If you want an HTTP response that can't be changed, if you want to get something from a database, or if you want to read from a local file, use `final`. Anything that isn't known at compile time should be `final` over `const`.

---

With all of that being said, both `const` and `final` cannot be reassigned, but fields in a `final` object, as long as they aren't `const` or `final` themselves, can be reassigned (unlike `const`).

Comment: The const keyword is used to represent a compile-time constant. Variables declared using the const keyword are implicitly final.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad you could check this video out [Dart Const vs Final](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5pe505l9_nE)

Comment: That last sentence really sums it up so well. Thanks for that.

Comment: Should we even care that const is an option? Is the performance gain really perceptible?

Comment: So this code:   ```void main() {
 var fruits = ['apples', 'bananas', 'oranges'];
 for ( final fruit in fruits) {
 print('I like to eat $fruit');
 }
}``` Will it print always the same?

Comment: Confusing as I've seen a lot of code using final for component props, yet the user can pass in new values when they like... so they are not final or the component class is completely re-created each render which sounds inefficient. I'm sure it's not the case but this is confusing to noobs like me

Comment: For those who are looking which is more appropriate or efficient https://stackoverflow.com/a/67603635/4531507

Comment: so for JS devs, `final` is like `const` in js

Comment: It would be great to include a similar explanation for `var` (as a bonus).

Answer (score 304):

#### Const

Value must be known at ***compile-time***, `const birthday  = "2008/12/25"` 
Can't be changed after initialized.

---

#### Final

Value must be known at ***run-time***, `final birthday = getBirthDateFromDB()` 
Can't be changed after initialized.

Comment: "Can't be changed after initialized" is ambiguous.  `final` variables can't be reassigned, but the object can be mutated.

Comment: Short but doesn't enough. A `final` object cannot be modified but its fields can be changed. https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=2078935ac3ac4fcb26e8f8e53b250889

Comment: Const also looks very interesting https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=ebc3f6f8e6345682f3ba865a409965ba

Answer (score 111):

Consolidated @Meyi and @faisal-naseer answers and Comparing with little programming.

### const:

const keyword used to make a variable to store a **compile time constant value**. Compile time constant value is a value which will be constant while compiling :-)

For example `5` is a compile time constant. While `DateTime.now()` which is not compile time constant. Because this method will return the **time when the line is getting executed** at runtime. So we can't assign the `DateTime.now()` to a `const` variable.

```
const a = 5;
// Uncommenting below statement will cause compile time error.
// Because we can't able to assign a runtime value to a const variable
// const b = DateTime.now();
```

Should be **initialized at the same line**.

```
const a = 5;
// Uncommenting below 2 statement will cause compilation error.
// Because const variable must be initialized at the same line.
// const b;
// b = 6;
```

All statements mentioned below are acceptable.

```
// Without type or var
const a = 5;
// With a type
const int b = 5;
// Uncommenting the below line causes a compilation error. Cause const can't be used with var.
// const var c = 6;
```

**Class level const variable** should be initialized like below.

```
Class A {
    static const a = 5;
}
```

**Instance level const variable is not possible**.

```
Class A {
    // Uncommenting below statement will give compilation error.
    // Because const is not possible to be used with instance level 
    // variable.
    // const a = 5;
}
```

The another major use of `const` is used to make the **object immutable**. To make a class object immutable we need to **use the const keyword with constructor** and make **all the fields as final** like mentioned below.

```
Class A {
    final a, b;
    const A(this.a, this.b);
}

void main () {
    // There is no way to change a field of object once it's 
    // initialized.
    const immutableObja = const A(5, 6);
    // Uncommenting below statement will give compilation error.
    // Because you are trying to reinitialize a const variable
    // with other value
    // immutableObja = const A(7, 9);

    // But the below one is not the same. Because we are mentioning objA 
    // is a variable of a class A. Not const. So we can able to assign
    // another object of class A to objA.
    A objA = const A(8, 9);
    // Below statement is acceptable.
    objA = const A(10, 11);
}
```

we can use **const keyword to a list**.

const a = const [] - A variable `a` **initialized as `const` which contains a list of `const` objects**(i.e., The list should contain only compile time constant and immutable objects). So **we can't able to assign `a` with another list**.

var a = const [] - A variable `a` **initialized as `var` which contains a list `const` objects**. So **we can able to assign another list to the variable `a`**.

```
Class A {
    final a, b;
    const A(this.a, this.b);
}

class B {
    B(){ // Doing something }
}

void main() {
    const constantListOfInt = const [5, 6, 7,
                 // Uncommenting below statement give compilation error.
                 // Because we are trying to add a runtime value
                 // to a constant list
                 // DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch
              ];
    const constantListOfConstantObjA = const [
        A(5, 6),
        A(55, 88),
        A(100, 9),
    ];
    // Uncommenting below 2 statements will give compilation error.
    // Because we are trying to reinitialize with a new list.
    // constantListOfInt = [8, 9, 10];
    // constantListOfConstantObjA = const[A(55, 77)];

    // But the following lines are little different. Because we are just
    // trying to assign a list of constant values to a variable. Which 
    // is acceptable
    var variableWithConstantList = const [5, 6, 7];
    variableWithConstantList = const [10, 11, 15];
    var variableOfConstantListOfObjA = const [A(5, 8), A(7, 9), A(10, 4)];
    variableWithConstantList = const [A(9, 10)];
}
```

---

### final:

final keyword also used to make the variable to **hold a constant value**. Once initialized we can't change the value.

```
final a = 5;
// Uncommenting below statement will give compilation error.
// Because a is declared as final.
// a = 6;
```

All statements mentioned below are acceptable.

```
// Without type or var
final a = 5;
// With a type
final int b = 5;
// Can't use var along with final keyword. Uncommenting below line cause compilation issue.
// final var c = 6;
```

Able to **assign a runtime value**.

```
// DateTime.now() will return the time when the line is getting
// executed. Which is a runtime value.
final a = DateTime.now();
var b = 5;
final c = b;
```

**Class level final variable** must be initialized in the same line.

```
Class A {
    static final a = 5;
    static final b = DateTime.now();
}
```

**Instance level final variable** must be initialized in the same line or in the constructor initialization. The value will be put into memory when the object is created.

```
Class A {
    final a = 5;
}

// Constructor with a parameter.
Class B {
    final b;
    B(this.b);
}

// Constructor with multiple parameter.
Class C {
    final c;
    C(this.c, int d) {
        // Do something with d
    }
}

void main() {
    A objA = new A();
    B objB = new B(5);
    C objC = new C(5, 6);
}
```

Assigning **a list**.

```
final a = [5, 6, 7, 5.6, A()];
// Uncommenting Below statement will give compilation error.
// Because we are trying to reinitialize the object with another list.
// a = [9.9, 10, B()];
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer! It also demonstrates the const collection defined as a literal, which is an important case nobody covered.

Comment: `const immutableObja = const A(5, 6);` can also be written as `const immutableObja = A(5, 6);` because `const A(5,6)` rather than `new A(5,6)` will be chosen by the smart Dart compiler.

Comment: Actually `final var c = 6;` is not allowed. Members declared cannot be declared to be both `final` and `var`.

Comment: @StefanRein As you mentioned, var should not be used along with the final. Updated the answer as well. Thanks for your input.

Comment: ```const var c = 6;```  is not acceptable on dart 2.19.6

Comment: @RobinZheng Thanks for bringing it. As you mentioned in the recent versions, const can't be used with var. Checked and Updated the answer based on your input.

Comment: Where it the tl;dr version of this?

Answer (score 30):

Extending the answer by @Meyi

- final variable can only be set once and it is initialized when
  accessed.(for example from code section below if you use the value of `biggestNumberOndice` only then the value will be initialized and memory will be assigned).
- const is internally final in nature but the main difference is that
  its compile time constant which is initialized during compilation
  even if you don't use its value it will get initialized and will take
  space in memory.
- Variable from classes can be final but not constant and if you want a
  constant at class level make it static const.

**Code:**

```
void main() {

    // final demonstration
    final biggestNumberOndice = '6';
    //  biggestNumberOndice = '8';     // Throws an error for reinitialization

    // const
    const smallestNumberOnDice = 1;

}

class TestClass {

    final biggestNumberOndice = '6';

    //const smallestNumberOnDice = 1;  //Throws an error
    //Error .  only static fields can be declared as constants.

    static const smallestNumberOnDice = 1;
}
```

Comment: I think a better way to ask the question is when to prefer runtime initialization over compile time initialization....

Comment: and for that you can consult @Meyi answer and also do visit the link of the article from his post its wonderful :)

Answer (score 17):

`const` means its initial value is must be fixed, can not be a dynamic value;

`final` means its initial value is must be fixed but can be a dynamic value, equal to the `var` with a fixed value.

### code demos

> const

```dart
void main() {
  const sum = 1 + 2;
  // ✅ const can not change its value
  print("sum = ${sum}");
  // ⚠️ Const variables must be initialized with a constant value.
  const time = new DateTime.now();
  // ❌ Error: New expression is not a constant expression.
  print("time = ${time}");
}
```

> final

```dart
// new DateTime.now();
// dynamic timestamp

void main() {
  final sum = 1 + 2;
  // ✅ final can not change its value
  print("sum = ${sum}");
  final time = new DateTime.now();
  // ✅ final === var with fixed value
  print("time = ${time}");
}
```

### Screenshots

[image]
[image]

### refs

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const

Answer (score 11):

`final` and `const` in dart are confusing to the level we think both of them are the same.

##### Let's see their differences :

[image]
[image]

> P.S. I included image instead of text as I couldn't tabulate the info
> in Stackoverflow .md format easily.

Answer (score 11):

Anything that isn't known at compile time should be `final` over `const`.

Answer (score 9):

Both `final` and `const` prevent a variable from being reassigned (similar to how `final` works in Java or how `const` works in JavaScript).

The difference has to do with how memory is allocated. Memory is allocated for a `final` variable at runtime, and for a `const` variable at compile-time. The `final` modifier should be the more commonly used, because many program variables won't need any memory since the program logic won't call for them to be initialized. With a `const` variable you are basically telling the computer, "Hey, I need memory for this variable up front because I know I'm going to need it."

Thinking of them in this way makes it easier to understand differences in their syntactical usage. Mainly that a `final` variable may be an instance variable, but a `const` must be a `static` variable on a class. This is because instance variables are created at runtime, and `const` variables--by definition--are not. Thus, `const` variables on a class must be `static`, which means simply that a single copy of that variable exists on a class, regardless of whether that class is instantiated.

This video breaks it down fairly simply:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ZZL3iyf4Vk

This article goes into more depth and explains a very important semantic difference between the two, i.e. `final` modifies variables and `const` modifies values, which essentially boils down to only being able to initialize `const` values which are derivable at compile-time.

https://news.dartlang.org/2012/06/const-static-final-oh-my.html

Answer (score 7):

If you are coming from `C++` then `const` in `Dart` is `constexpr` in `C++` and `final` in `Dart` is `const` in `C++`.

The above applies to primitive types only.
However in `Dart` objects marked `final` are mutable in terms of it's members.

Comment: Sort of.  I think you could say this for primitive types but not for objects.  `const` in C++ is almost always used to specify that an object is not mutable through a specific reference or pointer. `final` in Dart does not prevent the object from being mutated through that variable.

Answer (score 6):

Simple words:

**Const**

> Value must be known at **compile-time**, i.e. values coming from internal files.

Sample: API keys, supported languages of your app or any variables in your i.e. helper file, basically anything which you ship with your app.

**Final**

> Value must be known at **run-time**.

It can be data like above but also i.e. device info which will be checked when the app is starting or data that is loaded from API's or servers when the app starts, but before the app is ready to use i.e. you need to check if the user is logged in or not, your app would load or check a session token from the server.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
The answer is in the image itself.

Comment: Please do not answer with code as an image. This is terrible for the purpose of indexing and accessibility and forces people to retype said code if they want to experiment with it. Oh, and it's a waste of bandwidth I guess.

Answer (score 1):

`const` is a Compile-time constant.

`final` is a Run-time constant.

Comment: `final` variables cannot be *reassigned* but the object can be *mutated*.  They are not runtime constants.

Answer (score 1):

All these answers I can describe in a concise way.

```
const list = [1, 2, 3];
```

- Both variable/identifier & value are const. Like - `const list = const [1, 2, 3]`
- That's why they are not allowed to be re-assigned.
- Good fit for global variables.
- It is possible to use it as a class variable but have to set static. Like - `static const list = [1, 2, 3]`.

vs:

```
final list = [1, 2, 3];
```

- Variable/Identifier is const but value is not. Like - `const list = [1, 2, 3]`
- That's why we can perform like - `list.add(4)`

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialise a `const` using a `final`. For example :

```
  final myConst = 1;
  const myFinal = 2;

  final a = myConst; // possible
  final b = myFinal; // possible
  const c = myConst; // this is not possible
  const d = myFinal; // possible
```

Comment: While what you wrote is true, it's not a good explanation for what `const` and `final` mean.  Also, that you named the `const` object `myFinal` and the `final` variable `myConst` is very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

When to use which keyword?

A simple example for both:
Use final: If you don’t know what it’s value will be at compile-time. For example, when you can need to get data from an API, this happens when running your code.

Use const: If you are sure that a value isn’t going to be changed when running your code. For example, when you declare a sentence that always remains the same.

https://itnext.io/difference-between-const-and-final-in-dart-78c129d0c573

Answer (score 0):

A variable with the `final` keyword will be initialized at runtime and can only be assigned for a single time.

A variable with the `const` keyword is initialized at compile-time and is already assigned when at runtime.

Use `final`: If you don’t know what it’s value will be at compile-time. For example, when you can need to get data from an API, this happens when running your code.
Use `const`: If you are sure that a value isn’t going to be changed when running your code. For example, when you declare a sentence that always remains the same.

Answer (score -1):

Well, an unofficial but easy way to understand:

- **Compile time**: when you're coding
- **Run time**: when you run the application

So to be short,

- `final`: as long as in run time it's a constant. Its value is not needed in compile time, **assign** but **decide later** ie. `DatTime.now()`
- `const`: if a value is known and will be the same for both compile and run time. A value **always the same** ie. `int 10`

both value of `final` and `const` cannot be changed in the future (in run time)