# What is the purpose of assigning `const` value to a `final` variable in dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

So I was doing the [first example](https://flutter.io/get-started/codelab/) for Flutter, and under
Step 4: *Create an infinite scrolling ListView*,

I encountered this piece of code:

```
class RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
  final _suggestions = <WordPair>[];

  final _biggerFont = const TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0);
  ...
}
```

But I found the following line a little spooky.

```
final _biggerFont = const TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0);
```

My question is, what is the purpose of assigning a `const`ant value to a `final` variable?

I know that

> Compile-time constants are canonicalized,i.e. no matter how many times
>   you write `const MyObj(0, 0)`,you only create one object.

This may sound useful, but you can simply create the const variable to hold the value and use that variable instead.

Well, don't you think it's kinda redundant? I get it that the developers at Flutter wanted to create a compile-time constant object, but hey! you are assigning that value to a `final` variable. Which is somewhat the same thing.

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**

I googled some definitions, I found that

> `const` constructors cannot have a body and It's class must not have
>   any non-final fields

So is this the reason why we used the `const` keyword? Because if you'll look at the [`TextStyle`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_style.dart) class's design, you'll realize that they have done the exact same thing here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the difference in between ''const'' and ''final'' keyword in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50431055/608639)

Answer (score 5):

I personally think

```
final _biggerFont = const TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0);
```

looks like a mistake, and that that alone is reason enough to change it.

The member is only used inside the same class, so there is no reason not to make it `static`. Then it will not take up one extra memory location for each instance of the class, all pointing to the same value. (That's assuming the compiler doesn't recognize the field as always having the same value, and just inlines the value everywhere).

If the member is `static`, it might as well also be `const`, so I'd write it as:

```
static const _biggerFont = TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0);
```

This assumes that the code is what I found by searching for `final _biggerFont = const`.

If there is a subclass in the same library which overrides `_biggerFont`, then it does need to be an instance variable. It could still be a *getter* instead of a field, then. Whether that's an efficiency improvement depends on how the class is used, and how well a compiler optimizes a final field that always has the same value.

In any case, creating a private instance member which always has the same constant value looks like something that should just be a static constant to begin with, and code that looks like a mistake is confusing to read. I'd rewrite it (or document it) just for that reason - to avoid the reader being confused about why it is the way it is.

Comment: "As an opposing opinion" My intention was not to argue that it should not be static, just that changing it to `const` would be a breaking change. Lots of great information in your answer though, as always.

Comment: Good point, I'll change it to not be opposed :)

Comment: I guess I still didn't understand the reason behind that statement. And as I googled some definitions, I found that `const` constructors cannot have a body and It's class must not have any non-final fields, so is this the reason why we used the `const` keyword? Because if you'll look at the `TextStyle` class's design, you'll realise that they have done the exact same thing here.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_style.dart

Comment: "that statement" Not sure what you mean by that. You can have different const instances of a class with a const constructor, this is why the values are held by instance fields instead of static fields. Static fields can only have a single value per class. Canonicalization means that there won't be more than one const instance with the same constructor parameter values.

Comment: I guess I'm just too dumb to understand all this right now. I'm am unable to connect any of those explanations with my question, it's not that I am not getting what you are saying.

Comment: I found it confusing as well when I started working with Dart and to some degree still do, so I think this is no reason to worry. "purpose of assigning `const` value to a `final` variable in dart?" As lrn said it's probably not the best design if there is no specific reason to have it an instance field. My argument was that just replacing `final` with `const` won't work because `const` alone is invalid at this place - it would need to be `static const` and that might need to change code that uses the class.

Comment: So with an isolated view at the `RandomWordsState` class it's not entirely clear, but because the field is private it should be easy to make the necessary changes to make the code work with `static const _biggerFont = const TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0);`

Answer (score 0):

`const` values are canonicalized.

This means no matter how often your code contains

```
final _biggerFont = const TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0);
```

there will only a single `const TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)` instance.

Using const for class' fields requires `static`, this would not allow to access its value using a reference to an instance of `RandomWordsState`.

There are different preferences for classes with const constructors

http://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_field_initializers_in_const_classes.html

> AVOID field initializers in const classes.
>
> Instead of final x = const expr;, you should write get x => const
>   expr; and not allocate a useless field. As of April 2018 this is true
>   for the VM, but not for code that will be compiled to JS.

and top-level fields

http://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_const_declarations.html

> PREFER using const for const declarations.
>
> Const declarations are more hot-reload friendly and allow to use const
>   constructors if an instantiation references this declaration.

The IDE also suggests to replace `final` with `const` for local variables that are initialized with constant values

[image]

I haven't found where this suggestion comes from, but it makes sense because local variables can be `const` without `static`

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking, I didn't expect the developers at Flutter.io to make such a mistake so I decided to ask some fellow developers. Thanks :)

Comment: I can't accept the answer within 9 minutes, I'll mark it as answered ASAP! :)

Comment: @Dennis there was a mistake in my answer. See my updated answer.

Comment: But I did not get any suggestion in my IDE (IntelliJ Idea) :/

Comment: This is only inside a method or function. Might be the result of an enabled linter rule, but I haven't found which one.

Comment: After the update, I am unable to figure out the exact reason for that. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: See my comment under lrn's answer.