# Where to use final and const?

Tags: flutter, dart

Where and when to use each one of them ?
**const** and final in dart and any **exemple** or concept from app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between the "const" and "final" keywords in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431055/what-is-the-difference-between-the-const-and-final-keywords-in-dart)

Comment: Possible Concept [What is the purpose of assigning `const` value to a `final` variable in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51355904/what-is-the-purpose-of-assigning-const-value-to-a-final-variable-in-dart)