# How do I specify dynamic Duration times?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to dynamically increase duration time, but Dart only accepts the `const` keyword:

```dart
int ms=level*100+200;
const oneSec = const Duration(milliseconds: ms);
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: There is no scenario that only allows `const` values. That is impossible in Dart, i.e. it always occurs because your code specifies it that way. If you cannot pass `oneSec` if it is not `const`, then you should share the rest of your code.

Comment: Could you talk more on what you want to do?

Comment: ı want to run setState function periodically. For example, at first setState function  will work in 200 ms then  at second  will work 300 then ... bla bla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Duration` objects are immutable.  You cannot change a `Duration` after it's been constructed.  If you want to use increasing durations, you'll need to create a new one each time.  For example:

```dart
void repeatedSetStateWithDelay(int level) {
  setState(() {
    int ms = level * 100 + 200;
    Future.delayed(
      Duration(milliseconds: ms),
      () => repeatedSetStateWithDelay(level + 1),
    );
  });
}
```

I'm not sure what `const` has to do with your question; you should not be using `const` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to understand how `const` works, you can [refer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50431055/6509751).

---

In your case, you cannot use a **`const`** `Duration` because the **dynamic** value cannot be determined at compile time. This means that you will have to remove `const` and e.g. use `final`:

```dart
int ms = level * 100 + 200;
final oneSec = Duration(milliseconds: ms);
```

Comment: @BatuhanÖzkan Looking at the edits to your question, *you* changed the meaning of your own question when you changed "Dart does not accept the `const` keyword" to "Dart only accept the `const` keyword".  I'm not sure that you fully understand how `const` works; you do *not* and should *not* be using `const` at all since you're not using compile-time constants, and Dart will require using `const` objects only if *you* have already requested that it be in a `const` context.

Comment: @jamesdlin No. At first my question was " dart doesn't accept except const variable for duration time". Then creativecreatorormaybenot changed my question as"Dart does not accept the const keyword" so the meaning was changed. Then i  changed my question as"Dart only accept the const keyword"