# What is the best way to storage data in flutter

Tags: oop, flutter, design-patterns

For example, I have a class with a static field that can store my data, but I'm not sure if this is correct for OOP principles. What is the best way to do this?

```
class Data {
  static String token;
  static DoctorProfile doctor;
  static UserProfile userProfile;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its depends.

**const:** If the value is known at compile time you should use const.

> Use const for variables that you want to be compile-time constants. If
>   the const variable is at the class level, mark it static const. Where
>   you declare the variable, set the value to a compile-time constant
>   such as a number or string literal, a const variable, or the result of
>   an arithmetic operation on constant numbers:

```
const bar = 1000000; // Unit of pressure (dynes/cm2)
const double atm = 1.01325 * bar; // Standard atmosphere
```

**final:** If you do not know the value at compile time, but it would be generated at runtime.

> Final instance variables must be initialized before the constructor
>   body starts.

```
class Data {
  final String token;
  final DoctorProfile doctor;
  final UserProfile userProfile;

  Data({this.token, this.doctor, this.userprofile});
}
```

***Reference:***

1. [Final and const](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const) 
   2.[What is the difference between the “const” and
   “final” keywords in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431055/what-is-the-difference-between-the-const-and-final-keywords-in-dart)