# What is the use of constant values in dart?

Tags: dart

As described in the documentations:

> The const keyword isn’t just for declaring constant variables. You can also use it to create constant values, as well as to declare constructors that create constant values. Any variable can have a constant value.

Can someone explain the use of constant values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between the "const" and "final" keywords in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431055/what-is-the-difference-between-the-const-and-final-keywords-in-dart)

Answer (score 10):

This is a simple example which I hope explains clearly:

Start with two variables and a constant.

```
var foo = [10,11];
var bar = const [20,21];
const baz = [30,31];
```

Try to modify `foo` and it succeeds.

```
foo.add(12); // [10,11,12]
```

Try to similarly modify `bar` and there's an error, because even though `bar` is a variable, its *value* was declared to be a constant, thus is immutable.

```
bar.add(22); // ERROR!
```

Try to reassign a different value to `bar`. That works since `bar` itself was not declared as a constant.

```
bar = [40,41];
```

Now, try to modify `bar`'s value again and this time it works, since its new value is not a constant.

```
bar.add(42)  // [40,41,42]
```

Try to modify `baz` and there's an error, since `baz` being declared as a constant itself, its value is inherently immutable.

```
baz.add(32); // ERROR!
```

Try reassigning `baz` to a new value and it fails because `baz` is a constant and can't be reassigned to a new value.

```
baz = [50,51]; // ERROR!
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void main() {
  simpleUse();
  finalUse();
  constUse();
}

simpleUse() {
  print("\nsimple declaration");
  var x = [10];
  print('before: $x');
  x = [5];//changing reference allowed
  x.add(10);//changing content allowed
  print('after: $x');
}

finalUse() {
  print("\nfinal declaration");
  final x = [10];
  print('before: $x');

  // x = [10,20]; //nope changing reference is not allowed for final declaration

  x.add(20); //changing content is allowed
  print('after: $x');
}

constUse() {
  print("\nconst declaration");
  const x = [10];
  print('before: $x');

  // x = [10,20]; //nope -> changing reference is not allowed for final declaration

  // x.add(20);//nope -> changing content is not allowed
  print('after: $x');
}
```

Also, variables are simple values like `x = 10;`
values are instances of enums, list, maps, classes, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I want to add, that another point for `const` is to guarantee your get the same instance of the object each time you construct it with the same parameters:

```
class Test {
  final int value; 
  const Test(this.value);
}

void main() {
  print(Test(5).hashCode == Test(5).hashCode); // false
  print((const Test(5)).hashCode == (const Test(5)).hashCode); // true
}
```

This is the reason why the `const` constructor can be difficult to make for all objects since your need to make sure the object can be constructed on compile-time. Also, why after creation of the object no internal state can be changed as the previous answer also shows.