# Why I'm getting the error, Invalid constant value in flutter statfulwidget flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, statefulwidget

In the below  code widget.hintText is giving the error, I am trying to make the datepicker as the seperate component and dynamically pass the hinttext value whenever calling it from the other file.

```
import 'package:date_field/date_field.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class DatePicker extends StatefulWidget {
  final String hintText;
  DatePicker({
    this.hintText,
    Key key,
  }): super(key: key);

  @override
  _DatePickerState createState() => _DatePickerState();
}
class _DatePickerState extends State<DatePicker> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DateTimeFormField(
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    hintText: widget.hintText,
    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54,fontSize: 16),
    errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
    suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.event_note),
  ),
  mode: DateTimeFieldPickerMode.date,
  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
  // validator: (e) => (e?.day ?? 0) == 1 ? 'Please not the first day' : null,
  onDateSelected: (DateTime value) {
  },
);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error comes from the fact of using a variable `widget.hint` inside of const object `InputDecoration`

I can't find anywhere in the [date_field](https://github.com/GaspardMerten/date_field/blob/master/lib/date_field.dart) code where it forces you to use a constant `decoration`

So you might just remove the `const` keyword in front of `InputDecoration`

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431055/what-is-the-difference-between-the-const-and-final-keywords-in-dart) for details about the difference between `const` and `final`

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the **const** for the InputDecoration()

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the `final` keyword from the string

Comment: Yes I tried removing final keyword, but it gived error "This class (or a class that this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields aren't final"