# Declaring list in dart with const and modifying it giving runtime error not a compile time

Tags: flutter, dart

In dart, why
`const cities = ['Delhi', 'UP', 'Noida'];`

//error is in this line

`cities[0] = 'Mumbai';`
is a runtime error, not a compile time error?

Answer (score 0):

[https://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2468332&seqNum=5#:~:text=EXAMPLE%204.12&text=Unlike%20final%20variables%2C%20properties%20of,its%20values%20cannot%20be%20changed](https://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2468332&seqNum=5#:%7E:text=EXAMPLE%204.12&text=Unlike%20final%20variables%2C%20properties%20of,its%20values%20cannot%20be%20changed).

Use normal variables, as with constants, you cannot change the value of the list during runtime.
I assume that is done with
`var` or `final`, as I'm not a dart master myself.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431055/what-is-the-difference-between-the-const-and-final-keywords-in-dart) for knowing the implications of const in dart

> TLDR const variables are pre compile by dart and you cannot modify them at runtime.

```dart
const cities = ['Delhi', 'UP', 'Noida'];
  cities[0] = 'Mumbai'; // Throws at runtime
```

Use final or var instead.

```dart
final cities = ['Delhi', 'UP', 'Noida'];
  cities[0] = 'Mumbai'; // Works OK
```

Answer (score 0):

There currently is no way of indicating in Dart whether a method mutates its object or is guaranteed to leave it alone. (This is unlike, say, C++ where a method could be marked as `const` to indicate that it does not (visibly) mutate the object.)

Consequently, there isn't a good way for the Dart compiler to know that `operator []=` shouldn't be allowed to be invoked on a `const` object, so unfortunately it isn't known that it violates the `const`-ness of the object until runtime.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a list using the const keyword, it creates an immutable list, which means you cannot modify its elements or change its length. However, Dart's static analysis cannot catch this error during compilation because the add method is a valid method on a List object, and it can only be detected at runtime when you attempt to modify the immutable list.

Answer (score 0):

Others have mentioned that the static analyser does not catch it.

But the question is "Why is it like that?".

In comparison with languages like C++, it probably has to do with what the compilers compile into, in these languages. In C++, the compiler compiles to something like assembly or machine code. While in Dart, we compile into JavaScript, or into byte code for its Virtual Machine, which would be further compiled only during execution using the Just-In-Time (JIT) compiler