# Pass null to named constructer parameter with default value

Tags: flutter, dart

I made a class `HelloWorld` with a named constructer which accepts a single parameter named `test` which also has default value of `Default Value`. Here is my code:

```dart
import 'dart:core';

class HelloWorld {
  final String test;
  
  const HelloWorld({
    this.test = 'Default Value',
  });
}

void main() {
  const Map<String, dynamic> _json = {'hello': 'world'};
  const _helloWorld = HelloWorld(test: _json['test']);
  print(_helloWorld.test);
}
```

Then I made a map named `_json` which has only one key `hello`. Finally I tried to get the value of key `test` which obviously doesn't exist in `_json` which will return `null`. Despite having the default value for the `test` parameter in the named constructor, I still get this compilation error:

```
lib/main.dart:13:23:
Error: Constant evaluation error:
  const _helloWorld = HelloWorld(test: _json['test']);
                      ^
lib/main.dart:13:45:
Info: The method '[]' can't be invoked on '<String, dynamic>{"hello": "world"}' in a constant expression.
  const _helloWorld = HelloWorld(test: _json['test']);
                                            ^
lib/main.dart:13:9:
Info: While analyzing:
  const _helloWorld = HelloWorld(test: _json['test']);
        ^
Error: Compilation failed.
```

**Dart version**: `Dart SDK version: 2.14.4 (stable) (Wed Oct 13 11:11:32 2021 +0200) on "macos_x64"`

Answer (score 2):

> **const** means that the object's entire deep state can be determined entirely at compile time and that the object will be frozen and completely immutable.

`const Map<String, dynamic> _json = {'hello': 'world'};`  means this `_json` is  compile-time constant.

But for `_json['test']` it doesn't know what will be the value of it in compile time. It needs to go through the `_json` Map and find the value, and this will happen while running the code. For this reason `_helloWorld` can not be a const.

But if you do `HelloWorld(test: "others");` or use default value `HelloWorld()`, the `_helloWorld`  can be `const` type.

```dart
void main() {
  const Map<String, dynamic> _json = {'hello': 'world'};

  final _helloWorld = HelloWorld(test: _json['test']); // or can be use String
  print(_helloWorld.test);

  const _helloWorld1 = HelloWorld();
  print(_helloWorld1.test);
  const _helloWorld2 = HelloWorld(test: "on _helloWorld2");
  print(_helloWorld2.test);
}
```

Default value will be available only when you don't pass any value using `test`, it will be `const _helloWorld1 = HelloWorld();`.

But for handling null-Value from `_json` you can use   `HelloWorld(test: _json['test'] ?? "Got Null");`.  Passing `Got Null` because `test` require a non-nullable `String`. If you wish to have constructor default value in this case, check `_json['x']` provide null or not, then assign on `_helloWorld`.

```dart
  final _helloWorld = _json['test'] == null
      ? HelloWorld()
      : HelloWorld(test: _json['test']);
```

I will recommend  [const and final SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50431087/10157127)to learn more it. Also, you can find on [dart.dev](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour)

Comment: Yes because `_json['test']` doesn't exist on map. Does update answer clarify your doubt ?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this way:

```dart
import 'dart:core';

class HelloWorld {
  final String test;
  
  const HelloWorld({
    String? test,
  }) : test = test ?? 'Default Value';
}

void main() {
  final Map<String, dynamic> _json = {'hello': 'world'};
  final _helloWorld = HelloWorld(test: _json['test']);
  print(_helloWorld.test);
}
```

Comment: Can you please help us understand the code? Some comments(In code) would be helpful enough.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Because I didn't know this syntax was allowed until now, I found this post useful.

Answer (score -2):

You simply need to change your test variable to this, to make it nullable:

```
final String? test;
```

Comment: I don't want to make `test` nullable. That's the entire point. I set default value and I expect if `null` is passed to this parameter, the default value would be set!