# I am getting an Invalid constant value when refactoring my TextStyle widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter

```
Text(' '),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 35.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Cape Coast',
                      style: boldTextStyle(),
                    ),
```

After refractoring my TextStyle widget, It give an error of invalid constant value

Refactoring code is below

```
TextStyle boldTextStyle() {
    return const TextStyle(
      fontSize: 40,
      fontFamily: 'Dongle',
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> const means that the object's entire deep state can be determined entirely at compile time and that the object will be frozen and completely immutable.

On  `style: boldTextStyle(),` this style can be archived on runtime. Remove `const` from `Padding`

```dart
 Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 35.0),
          child: Text(
            'Cape Coast',
            style: boldTextStyle(),
          ),
        )
```

More about [const](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50431087/10157127)