# Not being able to pass bool value

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am getting error while trying to pass bool value to the TaskCheckbox() method. I am new to flutter and any help would be much appreciated

```dart
class _TaskTileState extends State<TaskTile> {
          bool? isChecked = false;
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return const ListTile(
              title: Text('This is a task'),
              trailing: TaskCheckbox(isChecked),
            );
          }
    
    }
    
    class TaskCheckbox extends StatelessWidget {
      final bool? checkboxState;
      const TaskCheckbox(this.checkboxState, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Checkbox(
          value: checkboxState,
          onChanged: (newValue) {},
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `const` before `ListTile` because the value will get on runtime.

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text('This is a task'),
      trailing: TaskCheckbox(isChecked),
    );
  }
```

> `const` keyword used to make a variable to store a compile time constant value. Compile time constant value is a value which will be constant while compiling , [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53999135/10157127)

Comment: I have been following Dr Angela Yu's flutter course. Are there any other materials online you would suggest to a someone like me who is completely new to programming??

Comment: I firstly suggest following official doc on flutter.dev and pub.dev , you can also find on flutter channel on youtube.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Stateful Class` widget for the build checkbox because we need to use setState for changing value inside the checkbox.

Use this code. This work fine for me:

```
class TaskTileState extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TaskTileState createState() => _TaskTileState();
}

class _TaskTileState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool? isChecked = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text('This is a task'),
      trailing: TaskCheckbox(isChecked),
    );
  }
}


class TaskCheckbox extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool? checkboxState;
  const TaskCheckbox(this.checkboxState, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TaskCheckbox> createState() => _TaskCheckboxState();
}

class _TaskCheckboxState extends State<TaskCheckbox> {
  bool? isChecked;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    isChecked = widget.checkboxState;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color getColor(Set<MaterialState> states) {
      const Set<MaterialState> interactiveStates = <MaterialState>{
        MaterialState.pressed,
        MaterialState.hovered,
        MaterialState.focused,
      };
      if (states.any(interactiveStates.contains)) {
        return Colors.blue;
      }
      return Colors.red;
    }

    return Checkbox(
      checkColor: Colors.black,
      fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(getColor),
      value: isChecked,
      onChanged: (bool? value) {
        setState(() {
          isChecked = value!;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Related from [@Yeasin Sheikh's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70183178/13096991) answer, you do have to remove the `const` in the `ListView`

Comment: I will use the Stateful Class widget like you mentioned :)