# Can't display const text in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `english-words` package and I try to get random word and display it in Text but I got error. What I am doing wrong?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final wordPair = WordPair.random();

    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.purple[900]),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('WordPair Generator')),
        body: const Center(child: Text(wordPair.asPascalCase))
        ));
  }
}
```

I get error at `Text(wordPair.asPascalCase)`:
Evaluation of this constant expression throws an exception.dart(const_eval_throws_exception)

Comment: From my Perspective removing const infront of the Center should make the analysis error disappear?

Comment: yes that solves my problem, thank you very much

Comment: Glad that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `const` keyword before the `Center` widget. you cant use a `const` widget if that widget has a none-constant data/variable at the build time.

Edit: [More on `const`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431055/what-is-the-difference-between-the-const-and-final-keywords-in-dart)