# Dart null safety with if check

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am use Dart Null Safety version

Have a widget:

[image]

**itemBuilder** expects a **Widget** type.

**footer** is **Widget?** type and will be null

Why Dart ignoring my null check? Also I only found one solution:

```
if (footer != null && index == data.length) {
    return footer ?? const SizedBox();
}
```

Comment: try this once

final _footer = footer;
if (_footer != null && index == data.length) {
    return _footer;
}

Comment: why it's not working as expected? Its explanation will be very long.

Comment: add `!` to footer. `return footer!;`

Comment: This is covered by https://dart.dev/tools/non-promotion-reasons

Answer (score 1):

Correct code:

```
final footer = this.footer;
if (footer != null && index == data.length) {
    return footer;
}
```

Why? Because subclass of this class can override footer getter.
i.e.:

```
Widget get footer {
  if (Random().nextBool()) return null;
  else return super.footer;
}
```

So every call to `footer` could return null.

Personally, I always do '!'(`if (footer != null) footer!`) after check. Because providing getter with side effects is a large code smell.

Answer (score 1):

> Why Dart ignoring my null check?

Because when the following code executed:

```
Widget? footer;

...
if (footer != null && index == data.length) {
    return footer;
}
```

There is a probability that your `footer` is set to `null` from the other part of your code hence the error is shown.

You can add `!` if you're completely sure that the `footer` won't be nulled for the rest of its life. So, you can use this:

```
if (footer != null && index == data.length) {
    return footer!;
}
```

but your solution much safer because it always check if `footer` not null:

```
if (footer != null && index == data.length) {
    // whenever footer is nulled, return SizedBox
    return footer ?? const SizedBox();
}
```

Comment: Your explanation is not right. If you declare footer as final (prevent any modification), the error would still be there.

Comment: @AlexandrFarkas: No final code in OP question.
`Although a final object cannot be modified, its fields can be changed. In comparison, a const object and its fields cannot be changed: they’re immutable.` https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const
  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431055/what-is-the-difference-between-the-const-and-final-keywords-in-dart

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code snippet to check that a variable is null or not

```
a != null && [do something]
```