# The constructor being called isn't a const constructor

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am getting an error for creating a Column Widget saying 'The constructor being called isn't a `const` constructor.' Having a tough time creating a Column Widget itself,

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() {
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'My First Flutter App',
            theme: ThemeData(
              scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
            ),
            home: const WelcomeScreen());
      }
    }

    class WelcomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      const WelcomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return const Scaffold(

          body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Login"),
              ]
            )
          );
        }}
```

[image: Screenshot of the error is pasted here]

Answer (score 2):

#### The error is at the level of the scaffold widget.

Just remove the **const** before scaffold. Then add **const** keyword before the children of your column widget.

That is how your code is supposed to be

```html
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() {
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'My First Flutter App',
            theme: ThemeData(
              scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
            ),
            home: const WelcomeScreen());
      }
    }

    class WelcomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      const WelcomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(

          body: Column(
              children: const <Widget>[
                Text("Login"),
                ...
              ]
            )
          );
        }}
```

Comment: You're welcome @SaumyaPrasad

Comment: I have a follow up question, why can't columns be constant?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `const` from `Scaffold` widget

Comment: and include on `Column(children: const [...]`

Comment: Remove the `const`  in `WelcomeScreen `'s build method. And check your IDE config, it must mark it as an error at compiling time

Comment: Thanks for the help! I had tried removing **const** from `Scaffold Widget` previously but didn't seem to work. Thanks for the help! It's working now.

Answer (score 1):

[`Column`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) is a non-const constructor

```dart
 Column({
    Key? key,
```

You can use `const` where everything is available as compile time constant. In this case, `Column` breaks the condition. You can use `const` before children, it is possible with `Text` for now

```dart
class WelcomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const WelcomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: const <Widget>[
        Text("Login"),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

I will encourage you to lean more about [`const`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour), you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50431055/10157127) and on [guides](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `const` from the `Scaffold` widget and it would work fine. But there will be another warning telling that the `Column` widget does not have `const`.

To fix that you can either put `const` in front of `<Widget>` or put `const` in front of the `children of columns`