# Calling a constructor is dynamic in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'dart:math';
void main(){
   const Rectangle bounds = const Rectangle(0, 0, 3, 4);
   print(bounds);
}
```

Rectangle constructor isn't getting called dynamically? Yes, it is returning a const but still doesn't it show that function will execute, compute something, and then decide on a value?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53999135/7706354

Comment: If `f()` is a method that can only be got on read Time, not compile time ? If you are asking about ` const vs final.`, it is already have been answer. Can you help me to get the specie question?

Comment: `Rectangle(0, 0, 3, 4);` Will this not be computed dynamically? @YeasinSheikh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Rectangle constructor isn't getting called dynamically? Yes, it is returning a const but still doesn't it show that function will execute, compute something, and then decide on a value?

"Dynamic" typically means something that can change and that is done at runtime.  Although the `Rectangle` constructor is being called, since it's being called in a `const` context, it creates a compile-time constant that is evaluated at *compilation* time.

`const` constructors are very limited in what they can do.  The compiler must be able to evaluate them at compilation time, which means that they cannot execute arbitrary code.  They cannot have constructor bodies, and usually they just initialize members by directly assigning them from construction arguments (which must also compile-time constants if the constructor is invoked in a `const` context).  In some cases, if the arguments are fundamental types (e.g. `bool`, `int`, `String`, etc.), there are some limited operations that can be done, such as comparing them or adding them together with `+`.