# final variables can't be reassigned, but the object can be mutated in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55990137/462608
comment:

> "Can't be changed after initialized" is ambiguous. final variables can't be reassigned, but the object can be mutated. –
> jamesdlin
> Feb 19 at 17:43

and https://stackoverflow.com/a/50431087/462608

> a final variable's value cannot be changed. final modifies variables

What do both these statements mean? Please give examples.

Comment: You can't do `final a = 5; a = 6;` or `final b = createSomeObject(1); b= createSomeObject(2);` but you can do `final b = createSomeObject(1); b.someProperty = 2` (if `someProperty` isn't final itself)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following class:

```
class SampleObject {
  int id;
  String value;
  
  SampleObject(this.id, this.value);
}
```

final variable can't be reassigned:

```
void main() {
  final obj1 = SampleObject(1, "value1");

  // the following line will gives error:
  // The final variable 'obj1' can only be set once
  obj1 = SampleObject(1, "value2");
}
```

But the object property can be changed (is mutable):

```
void main() {
  final obj1 = SampleObject(1, "value1");
  obj1.value = "value2";

  print(obj1.value);
}
```

But it becomes an immutable object if you set all the property in the class to final:

```
class SampleObject {
  final int id;
  final String value;
  
  SampleObject(this.id, this.value);
}
```

where it gives error when you're trying to reassign a value to its property:

```
void main() {
  final obj1 = SampleObject(1, "value1");

  // the following line will gives error:
  // 'value' can't be used as a setter because it's final.
  // Try finding a different setter, or making 'value' non-final
  obj1.value = "value2";
}
```

Comment: It can't be more precise than this explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine the example below:

```
void main() {
  final student = Student('Salih', 29);
  print('Student before $student');
  student.age = 30;
  print('Student after $student');
}


class Student {
  Student(this.name, this.age);
  
  final String name;
  int age;
  
  @override
  String toString() => 'Age is $age and name is $name';
}
```

One of the fields of the Student object is mutable. This way we can reassign it. What others mean above is that, the object reference of the `final` variables will be assigned first but internals of the object can be changed.

In our example, `final` would be preventing to re-assign something to student object but it will not prevent us to re-assign a value within the object.

You can run the code on dartpad.dev above and see the result as follows:

```
Student before Age is 29 and name is Salih
Student after Age is 30 and name is Salih
```