# "Invalid constant value" when trying to create a dynamic TextInput widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a new `TextInput` widget for customizing `TextFormField` but i can't customize `labelText`. I need to send in constructor `labelText` for my  `TextFormField` and show this String.

```
class TextInput extends StatelessWidget {


 final TextEditingController textControler;
 final String textLabelHint;
 const TextInput({Key? key, required this.textControler,required this.textLabelHint}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
    child: TextFormField(
    controller: textControler,
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      labelText: textLabelHint, 
    ),
  ),
);
  }
}
```

But I have problem:

```
labelText: textLabelHint, //Invalid constant value.
```

Answer (score 3):

You ned to remove `const` from  `decoration: const InputDecoration(...)`, since `textLabelHint` isn't a `const` value:

```
class TextInput extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController textControler;
  final String textLabelHint;
  const TextInput(
      {Key? key, required this.textControler, required this.textLabelHint})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: textControler,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          labelText: textLabelHint,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yes yes is work .... I would like to ask when should I use const? When you make an object that does not change?

Comment: @Stefan `const` is for _compile_ time, `final` is for run time. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431055/what-is-the-difference-between-the-const-and-final-keywords-in-dart) answer

Answer (score 1):

This error is there because `textLabelHint` is a final class property (not const) that could change based on the constructor value. However, where you try to pass this value is `InputDecoration` which you have marked as `const`. Thus, the error indicates that.

To resolve the issue, remove the `const` keyword before the `InputDecoration`:

```
class TextInput extends StatelessWidget {
 final TextEditingController textControler;
 final String textLabelHint;
 const TextInput({Key? key, required this.textControler,required this.textLabelHint}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
    child: TextFormField(
    controller: textControler,
    decoration: InputDecoration( // <-- Notice the removed const
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      labelText: textLabelHint, 
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: yes yes is work .... I would like to ask when should I use const? When you make an object that does not change?

Comment: Check this in the [Dart language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class TextInput extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController textControler;
  final String textLabelHint;
  const TextInput(
      {Key? key, required this.textControler, required this.textLabelHint})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: textControler,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
          labelText: textLabelHint,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```