# There is an error even though the value type has no error (Invalid constant value)

Tags: flutter, list, dart, colors

```
List<MaterialColor?> changeColor = [
    Colors.red,
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.yellow,
    Colors.green,
    Colors.pink,
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'Mohammed is coming back ',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: changeColor[_counter],
                fontSize: 22,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
```

I made a list consisting of a set of colors and I want to give it to the color but it keeps giving me this error, even though I gave the list type the same as the color type

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_counter` value will change and get on read time. That's why `Text` widget can not be const. Remove const from Text.

```dart
body: Center(
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(
        'Mohammed is coming back ',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: changeColor[_counter],
          fontSize: 22,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

You can more about

- [const on dart.dev](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const) and
- a good question on [difference between the "const" and "final" keywords in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50431055/10157127)