# error when passing class parameter - widget StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a class to later instantiate each contact field of a contact book(first name, last name, phone, email, etc) I want to pass a string as a parameter via constructor, but when using this variable inside the widget, it gives an error.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class campoContato extends StatefulWidget {
  final String labelName;

  const campoContato({Key? key, required this.labelName}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<campoContato> createState() => _campoContatoState();
}

class _campoContatoState extends State<campoContato> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          labelText: widget.labelName, // < ERROR HERE. IT DOES NOT ALLOW USING THE LABEL NAME
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide:
              BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.black))),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm going to use a class in another part of the code. If anyone can suggest anything, I'd appreciate it!

I already tried to start the variable with final, var, late but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `const`. You will get `labelName` on runtime

```dart
 decoration: InputDecoration( //here
```

You can check [this question about const](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50431055/10157127)

Comment: Glad to help, you can explore the attached link for more