# Error with Sizebox and Image.asset, can you help me?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem with Flutter.... I don't understand why the elements are underlined in red... Can you help me?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LandingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const LandingScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: const [
            SizedBox(height: 50),
            Text(
              'Welcome to app',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 33,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: size.height / 9),
            Image.asset(
              'assets/bg.png',
              height: 340,
              width: 340,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is the photo with the code underlined in red

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this method,

```
          Image(
                image: const AssetImage("assets/bg.png"),
                height: 340,
                width: 340,
                  ),
```

Full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LandingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const LandingScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: const [
            SizedBox(height: 50),
            Text(
              'Welcome to app',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 33,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: size.height / 9),
            Image(
                image: const AssetImage("assets/bg.png"),
                height: 340,
                width: 340,
             ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is coming because you are using `const` on   `children:  const [`.

But you are reading `size.height` on runtime. Therefore it can't be `const`.

You can do

```dart
class LandingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const LandingScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 50),
            const Text(
              'Welcome to app',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 33,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: size.height / 9),
            Image.asset(
              'assets/bg.png',
              height: 340,
              width: 340,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can check ["const" and "final" keywords in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50431055/10157127)