# Why do only constant constructors in Dart, not non-constant constructor, can't assign different type of value?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting error "A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'String' in a const constructor." from const Text().

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title, required this.subTitle});
  final String title;
  final String subTitle;
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          widget.title,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text(
            widget.subTitle,
          ),
      ),
    )
  }
}
```

I already know I have to remove const to resolve the error. But Could anyone explain why does only const constructor have this error?

Comment: Are you certain that's the error you're getting?  Is this your exact code?  Using `const Text` there is not allowed, but the error shouldn't be saying anything about `Null` since `widget.subTitle` is non-nullable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `const Constructor` expects `const parameters` or must be able to be evaluated as const at compilation time.

And you are trying to pass widget with a `non-constant` value .And this gives you error because they cannot be evaluated at compile time.

You have two possible solution:

1. remove the const from the `Text` widget.

```
Text(widget.subTitle),
```

2. make `tilte` a `const` variable.

```
const MyHomePage({..., required final const this.subTitle});
final const String subTitle;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `widget.subTitle` will get on runtime, instead of compile time. Another thing is `subTitle` is final , not `const`.

You can check  [What is the difference between the "const" and "final" keywords in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50431055/10157127)