# Invalid constant value for a list item value that I am trying to determine its Boolean value to decide Font weight of list tile

Tags: flutter, list, dart, flutter-list-tile

Invalid constant error message for item.header.

It is a boolean value representing if the list tile is going to have a bold or normal font-weight.

```dart
 child: ListTile(
        key: ValueKey(item.stuffId),
        title: Text(
          item.name,
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.blue,           
            fontWeight: item.header == true ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,                   
          ),
        ),
```

Here is the list that I used:

```
  final List<Stuff> _items = [
    Stuff(stuffId: "1", name: "Toiletries", header: true),
    Stuff(stuffId: "2", name: "Toothpaste", header: false),
    Stuff(stuffId: "3", name: "Hair brush", header: false),
    Stuff(stuffId: "4", name: "Nail clippers", header: false),
  ];
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfZg9.jpg)

'Toiletries' is the header and therefore supposed to be bold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ListTile(
        key: ValueKey(item.stuffId),
        title: Text(
          item.name,
          style: TextStyle( //  remove const here 
            color: Colors.blue,           
            fontWeight: item.header == true ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,                   
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

`item.header` will get/check on runtime, it cant be const , remove `const`

```dart
style: TextStyle(
```

Find more about [What is the difference between the "const" and "final" keywords in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50431055/10157127)

Comment: Thanks Yeasin for the answer. I didn't declare constant anywhere. The list is final, has a property header that is a boolean declared as bool header. There is no const to remove.

Comment: it is on top level  `style: const TextStyle(`