# Why is there an index invalid constant error while using Gnav in Google Nav Bar?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
final int selectedIndex = 0;
var heightOfDevice = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
return SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(
    bottomNavigationBar: const GNav(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF242A38),
      color: Colors.white,
      activeColor: Color(0xFFF54B64),
      gap: 8,
      onTabChange: (index) {
        
        // Here the index is raising error as invalid constant value
      },
      tabs: [
        GButton(
          icon: Icons.home,
          text: 'Home',
        ), // Etc.
      ]
    )
  )
)
```

I don't know why I am getting that error, I have initialized everything correctly, I want to navigate to another page but here I am getting stopped, as the index is raising the error as invalid constant.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `GNav` const with current structure because you are calling (executing) the function which will be on runtime rather than compile time.

```dart
bottomNavigationBar: GNav(
  onTabChange: (index) {}
```

But you can create function and pass it on `onTabChange:functionName` and it can be const.

```dart
void onTapChange(int index) {
  print(index);
}
....
bottomNavigationBar: const GNav(
  onTabChange: onTapChange,
```

You can check [What is the difference between the "const" and "final" keywords in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50431055/10157127)

Comment: can you please explain in detail, i am trying hard but cant able to rectify

Comment: you can just remove the const  like `bottomNavigationBar: GNav(`

Comment: ok yup thanks i got it !!